# В какой момент применяется выражение WHERE в запросе к представлению?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

В какой момент применяется выражение `WHERE` в запросе к представлению, в момент формирования набора записей представления или к уже сформированному набору и зависит ли это от каких-либо факторов?

**Интересуют два таких частных случая:**

**1.** В случае с простым запросом в теле представления
**2.** В случае, когда в запросе, формирующем представление, используются окна

**Пример 1**:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_StockRemnants
AS
     SELECT tt.PKID AS ИД,
            tt.Name AS Наименование,
            tt.priceIn AS Вход,
            tt.Price AS Цена
     FROM Item AS tt
     WHERE tt.iditem IS NOT NULL;

SELECT *
FROM vw_StockRemnants
WHERE dbo.vw_StockRemnants.[ИД] = 12345;
```

**Пример 2:**

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_StockRemnants
AS
     WITH CTE([ИД],
              [Наименование],
              [Вход],
              [Цена],
              rnumber,
              rcount)
          AS (SELECT tt.PKID AS ИД,
                     tt.Name AS Наименование,
                     tt.priceIn AS Вход,
                     tt.Price AS Цена,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tt.pkid ORDER BY tt.sn) AS rnumber,
                     COUNT(tt.sn) OVER(PARTITION BY tt.pkid) AS rcount
              FROM Item AS tt
              WHERE tt.iditem IS NOT NULL)
          SELECT *
          FROM CTE AS c
          WHERE c.rcount = 1;

SELECT *
FROM vw_StockRemnants
WHERE dbo.vw_StockRemnants.[ИД] = 12345;
```

Comment: Если представление встраивается (подставляется) в тело основного запроса - то как решит планировщик. Если же набор записей представления материализуется (емнип в случае с WITH возможен только этот вариант) - несомненно по завершении материализации. Иными словами, условие в тело представления не переносится. А вот наличие в теле представления оконных функций вряд ли влияет.

Comment: А еще это поведение может отличаться в разных версиях sql-server, и еще кучи разных факторов (например количестве записей в таблицах). Лучше проверяйте непосредственно на вашей версии и ваших данных, исследуя план выполнения запроса

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При выполнении запроса с использованием *view* (а также с использованием *inline table-valued function*) оптимизатор подставит определение *view* в запрос и попытается оптимизировать получившийся в результате подстановки составной запрос.

В первом случае запрос скорее всего выполнится как

```
SELECT
    tt.PKID AS ИД,
    tt.Name AS Наименование,
    tt.priceIn AS Вход,
    tt.Price AS Цена
FROM Item AS tt
WHERE tt.iditem IS NOT NULL AND tt.PKID = 12345;
```

А во втором, по-видимому, как

```
WITH CTE([ИД],
    [Наименование],
    [Вход],
    [Цена],
    rnumber,
    rcount)
AS (SELECT tt.PKID AS ИД,
        tt.Name AS Наименование,
        tt.priceIn AS Вход,
        tt.Price AS Цена,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tt.pkid ORDER BY tt.sn) AS rnumber,
        COUNT(tt.sn) OVER(PARTITION BY tt.pkid) AS rcount
    FROM Item AS tt
    WHERE tt.iditem IS NOT NULL AND tt.PKID = 12345)
SELECT *
FROM CTE AS c
WHERE c.rcount = 1;
```

т.к. во внутреннем запросе нумерация и подсчёт количества происходят в группах, разбитых по `tt.PKID`, а предикат `tt.PKID = 12345`, так же как и `c.rcount = 1`, делает фильтрацию группы.

---

При построении плана запроса оптимизатор старается применять предикаты настолько рано, насколько это возможно (т.н. *predicate pushdown* или *filter pushdown*), т.к., во-первых, выгодно на ранних этапах плана отсечь ненужные данные (меньше работы на следующих этапах), и, во-вторых, раннее применение предиката положительно сказывается на возможности использования индексов.

Рассмотрим пример. Пусть есть таблица

```
DECLARE @item TABLE(A int, B int);
INSERT INTO @item VALUES (1, 2), (2, NULL);
```

Выполним запрос с подзапросом

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM @item
    WHERE B IS NOT NULL
    ) I
WHERE A = 1;
```

и посмотрим план выполнения (графический и текстовый)

[image: plan 1]

```
|--Table Scan(OBJECT:(@item), WHERE:([A]=(1) AND [B] IS NOT NULL))
```

Как видим, оптимизатор объединил оба условия и поместил их в узел *Table Scan* (чтение данных таблицы).

Если бы запрос исполнялся именно так как он записан, то мы бы увидели

[image: plan 2]

```
|--Filter(WHERE:([A]=(1))
  |--Table Scan(OBJECT:(@item), WHERE:([B] IS NOT NULL))
```

т.е. чтение таблицы с условием `[B] IS NOT NULL` как первый этап плана, и фильтрацию набора строк с условием `[A]=(1)` как второй его этап. В данном случае вряд ли это заметно понизило бы производительность. Если бы, однако, на столбце `[A]` у нас был индекс, то такой план не позволил бы его использовать оптимально (или даже вовсе).

Однако для применения *predicate pushdown* у оптимизатора должно быть достаточно оснований. Препятствовать этому виду оптимизации может использование в предикатах недетерминированных выражений (в т.ч. с участием пользовательских скалярных функций). Также ни один вид оптимизации не должен нарушать семантику запроса (корректность результата превыше скорости).

Смоделируем второй случай. Пусть есть таблица с данными

```
DECLARE @item TABLE (A int, B int, C char(1));
INSERT INTO @item VALUES
    (1, NULL, NULL), (1, 1, 'X'),
    (2, 1, NULL),
    (3, NULL, NULL), (3, 1, NULL), (3, 1, 'Y'),
    (4, NULL, NULL), (4, 1, 'Z');
```

Мы делаем запрос

```
WITH R1 AS (
    SELECT
        A, B, C,
        Num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A ORDER BY C),
        Cnt = COUNT(C) OVER(PARTITION BY A)
    FROM @item
    WHERE B IS NOT NULL
),
R2 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM R1
    WHERE Cnt = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM R2
WHERE A = 1;
```

семантика которого такова:

1. Выбираем данные, делаем нумерацию и подсчёт в группах по `A`
2. Берём только группы с `COUNT(C) = 1`
3. Оставляем только записи с `A = 1`

План выполнения запроса

[image: plan 3]

```
|--Filter(WHERE:([Expr1004]=(1)))
  |--Nested Loops(Inner Join)
    |--Table Spool
      |  |--Segment
      |    |--Sequence Project(DEFINE:([Expr1003]=row_number))
      |      |--Segment
      |        |--Sort(ORDER BY:([C] ASC))
      |          |--Table Scan(OBJECT:(@item), WHERE:([A]=(1) AND [B] IS NOT NULL))
      |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, WHERE:((1)))
        |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1004]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1007],0)))
        |  |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([Expr1007]=COUNT([C])))
        |    |--Table Spool
        |--Table Spool
```

показывает, однако, что условие `A = 1`, заданное на последнем этапе, оптимизатор перенёс на первый этап, объединив его с `[B] IS NOT NULL` в узле *Table Scan*.

Если изменить запрос, убрав `PARTITION BY`, например

```
WITH R1 AS (
    SELECT
        A, B, C,
        Num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY C),
        Cnt = COUNT(C) OVER()
    FROM @item
    WHERE B IS NOT NULL
),
R2 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM R1
    WHERE Cnt = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM R2
WHERE A = 1;
```

то это меняет семантику запроса так, что оптимизатор уже не может применить условие `[A] = 1` при чтении данных из таблицы, и в плане запроса

```
|--Filter(WHERE:([A]=(1) AND [Expr1004]=(1)))
  |--Nested Loops(Inner Join)
    |--Table Spool
    |  |--Segment
    |    |--Sequence Project(DEFINE:([Expr1003]=row_number))
    |      |--Segment
    |        |--Sort(ORDER BY:([C] ASC))
    |          |--Table Scan(OBJECT:(@item), WHERE:([B] IS NOT NULL))
    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, WHERE:((1)))
      |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1004]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1007],0)))
      |  |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([Expr1007]=COUNT([C])))
      |    |--Table Spool
      |--Table Spool
```

мы видим в свойствах *Table Scan* лишь условие `[B] IS NOT NULL`, а условие `[A]=(1)` применяется в *Filter* на самом последнем этапе.